# How to extract sentences between point and brackets with R?

Tags: r, regex

I Have:

> Stringa=" This is diﬀerent from primary data created speciﬁcally by researchers to reﬂect concepts that are higher-order and more abstract(Lee,1991;Walsham,1995).Given the major diﬀerences between big data and research-collected data, it is surprising how little discussion has arisen about how using big data should change the practice of theory-informed IS research. Some scholars have noted that the very nature of inquiry is likely to change, given that large data sets, advanced algorithms, and powerful computing capabilities can initiate and reﬁne questions without human intervention (Agarwal & Dhar, 2014). Other commentators argue that the scientiﬁc method is likely to become obsolete, as with the “availability of huge amounts of data, along with the statistical tools to crunch these numbers … science can advance even without coherent models, uniﬁed theories, or really any mechanistic explanation at all” (Anderson, 2008). Perhaps “scientists no longer have to make educated guesses, construct hypotheses and models, test them in data-based experiments andexamples. Instead, they canmine thecomplete setof data forpatterns that reveal eﬀects, producing scientiﬁcconclusions without further experimentation” (Prensky, 2009). "

Desidered Output:

```
[1]This is diﬀerent from primary data created speciﬁcally by researchers to reﬂect concepts that are higher-order and more abstract(Lee,1991;Walsham,1995).
[2]Some scholars have noted that the very nature of inquiry is likely to change, given that large data sets, advanced algorithms, and powerful computing capabilities can initiate and reﬁne questions without human intervention (Agarwal & Dhar, 2014)
[3] Other commentators argue that the scientiﬁc method is likely to become obsolete, as with the “availability of huge amounts of data, along with the statistical tools to crunch these numbers … science can advance even without coherent models, uniﬁed theories, or really any mechanistic explanation at all” (Anderson, 2008)
[4]Instead, they canmine thecomplete setof data forpatterns that reveal eﬀects, producing scientiﬁc conclusions without further experimentation” (Prensky, 2009)
```

I use:`unlist(str_extract_all(string =Stringa, pattern =  "\\. [A-Za-z][^()]+ \\("))`
But it doesn't work

I don’t want extract ‘Given the major diﬀerences between big data and research-collected data, it is surprising how little discussion has arisen about how using big data should change the practice of theory-informed IS research. ‘ and ‘Perhaps “scientists no longer have to make educated guesses, construct hypotheses and models, test them in data-based experiments andexamples. ‘

Answer (score 1):

If there are no abbreviations in the text, you may use

```
regmatches(Stringa, gregexpr("[^.?!\\s][^.!?]*?\\([^()]*\\)", Stringa, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "This is diﬀerent from primary data created speciﬁcally by researchers to reﬂect concepts that are higher-order and more abstract(Lee,1991;Walsham,1995)"                                                                                                                                                                         
[2] "Some scholars have noted that the very nature of inquiry is likely to change, given that large data sets, advanced algorithms, and powerful computing capabilities can initiate and reﬁne questions without human intervention (Agarwal & Dhar, 2014)"                                                                           
[3] "Other commentators argue that the scientiﬁc method is likely to become obsolete, as with the “availability of huge amounts of data, along with the statistical tools to crunch these numbers … science can advance even without coherent models, uniﬁed theories, or really any mechanistic explanation at all” (Anderson, 2008)"
[4] "Instead, they canmine thecomplete setof data forpatterns that reveal eﬀects, producing scientiﬁcconclusions without further experimentation” (Prensky, 2009)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LN8tIN/1) and the  [R demo](https://ideone.com/7ezmhp).

**Details**

- `[^.?!\\s]` - any char but `.`, `?`, `!` and whitespace
- `[^.!?]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `.`, `?`, `!` as few as possible
- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this using `grepexpr` and `regmatches`, using the following regex pattern:

```
.*?\([^)]+\).*?(?=\w|$)
```

This will capture any content up to the first parenthesis, followed by a `(...)` term.  The script below will capture all such matches in the source text.

```
m <- gregexpr(".*?\\([^)]+\\).*?(?=\\w|$)", x, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)

[[1]]
[1] "This is diﬀerent from primary data created speciﬁcally by researchers to reﬂect concepts that are higher-order and more abstract(Lee,1991;Walsham,1995)."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[2] "Given the major diﬀerences between big data and research-collected data, it is surprising how little discussion has arisen about how using big data should change the practice of theory-informed IS research. Some scholars have noted that the very nature of inquiry is likely to change, given that large data sets, advanced algorithms, and powerful computing capabilities can initiate and reﬁne questions without human intervention (Agarwal & Dhar, 2014). "
[3] "Other commentators argue that the scientiﬁc method is likely to become obsolete, as with the “availability of huge amounts of data, along with the statistical tools to crunch these numbers … science can advance even without coherent models, uniﬁed theories, or really any mechanistic explanation at all” (Anderson, 2008). "
[4] "Perhaps “scientists no longer have to make educated guesses, construct hypotheses and models, test them in data-based experiments andexamples. Instead, they canmine thecomplete setof data forpatterns that reveal eﬀects, producing scientiﬁcconclusions without further experimentation”(Prensky, 2009). "
```